# -Djava.library.path not linking .so library

Tags: java, linux, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

I need to link a particular library when executing a `.jar` application.
I have modified the variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and added (as the first directory) the path of the folder containing the desired library. I have also tried to execute the appplication using the option `-Djava.library.path="path_to_.so"`, but with the same result.

In concrete, the result I am obtaining is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /.../application/lib64/libshmlib.so: 
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /.../another_application/lib64/libshmlib.so)
```

Are there any other options to load libraries besides the mentioned before?

Comment: You need a copy of `libshmlib.so` compiled on a version of linux that has the same or an older version of `libc` than the one that you're running on. The complaint is typically caused because you're running with a version of `libc` that is older than the version of `libc` that the library was built with, and this error is to tell you that older stuff may not be able to run newer stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LD_PRELOAD='path/of/lib.so' ./program` basically loads that given library before any other when executing the given program. So it is the best option if you need to load a concrete library

Answer (score 0):

If "the desired library" is `libshmlib.so` and it was its path that you have passed in various ways, then it seems that the library was actually found, but it requires the C library of the wrong version. For example, your library may be compiled against newer version of the `libc.so` than that you have on this system. If you have the sources of `libshmlib.so`, then try to recompile it on your system. If you don't, try to obtain the suitable `libshmlib.so` version for your operating system version. Or you may want to add path to these unresolved dependencies to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but it is probably not the case for `libc.so`, because trying to substitute the `libc.so` seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to download the libraries that libshmlib.so was asking for and then execute the program with `LD_PRELOAD='path/of/downloaded/lib.so'`. It works as it should now.